# Error running web service online

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery-mobile, phpmyadmin

I created a web service using php. Running it locally (localhost) works, but if run in an online server, it does not work. It displays this error below:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/look4biz/public_html/mobile/include/DB_Connect.php on line 19
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/look4biz/public_html/mobile/include/DB_Connect.php on line 19
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/look4biz/public_html/mobile/include/DB_Connect.php on line 22
>
> Warning: mysql_select_db(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/look4biz/public_html/mobile/include/DB_Connect.php on line 22
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/look4biz/public_html/mobile/include/DB_Functions.php on line 43
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/look4biz/public_html/mobile/include/DB_Functions.php on line 43
> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: i think in your cnfiguration on live database credentials are not correct please verify it

Comment: What online server did you upload your web service to? It's with the database configurations. Yes

Answer (score 0):

open your Db_connect.php then make sure username, password and database for your configuration is correct.

Comment: Db_connect.php configurations all right but not working ?

Comment: check port 3307 is open for your hosting domain.. ?